# How to deal with 407 error code in Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I have a RESTFul API which might respond with error code 407 if there is a specific problem, but when I use Volley, it shows that:

```
error.networkResponse = null
error.detailMessage = "java.net.ProtocolException: Received HTTP_PROXY_AUTH (407) code while not using proxy".
```

Is there a way that makes Volley shows this error in this variable error.networkResponse.statusCode? or I have to search in the error.detailMessage for 407?

Here is my code:

```
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(
            Request.Method.POST,
            url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    /*do something*/
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    if(error != null && error.networkResponse != null) {
                        switch (error.networkResponse.statusCode) {
                            case 400:
                                /* print appropriate response */
                            case 407:
                                /* print appropriate response, 
                                   it won't reach here because 
                                   the error.networkResponse = null*/
                            default:

                        }
                    }
            }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("id", String.format("%d", id));
            return params;
        }
    };
```

Comment: The status code 407 refers to Proxy Authentication. You have to pass your credentials for the proxy in the Proxy-Authenticate header field in header function

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using Volley with OkHttp, as that exception is specific to OkHttp.

I'm not using OkHttp myself so I don't know if this will work, but you could try overriding the `parseNetworkResponse` method of the request:

```
@NonNull
@Override
protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    int statusCode = response.statusCode;

    return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
}
```